# How to initialize Specification of Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, dynamicquery

I have a method that does a search with filters, so I'm using [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) to build a dynamic query:

```
public Page<Foo> searchFoo(@NotNull Foo probe, @NotNull Pageable pageable) {

        Specification<Foo> spec = Specification.where(null);  // is this ok?

        if(probe.getName() != null) {
            spec.and(FooSpecs.containsName(probe.getName()));
        }
        if(probe.getState() != null) {
            spec.and(FooSpecs.hasState(probe.getState()));
        }
        //and so on...

        return fooRepo.findAll(spec, pageable);
}
```

There is the possibility that there are no filters specified, so I would list everything without filtering. So having that in mind, how I should initialize `spec` ? Right now, the code above doesn't work as it always returns me the same result: all the registers of the table, no filtering have been aplied althought `and` operations have been made.

FooSpecs:

```
public class PrescriptionSpecs {

    public static Specification<Prescription> containsCode(String code) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(Prescription_.code), "%" + code + "%");
    }

    // some methods matching objects...
    public static Specification<Prescription> hasContractor(Contractor contractor) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Prescription_.contractor), contractor);
    }
    //... also some methods that access nested objects, not sure about this
    public static Specification<Prescription> containsUserCode(String userCode) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(Prescription_.user).get(User_.code), "%" + userCode + "%");
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? I think this should work. Please add the stack trace. Also, why do you ask "is this ok?" if you already know "the code above doesn't work"

Comment: @JensSchauder There is no error but it doesn't filter. I'm getting all the results of the table, always. I ask if its is ok because I'm not sure if it is, I didn't see an example like this. Moreover, when I debug, i see `spec` empty.

Comment: I see. Can you share the code for `FooSpecs`?

Comment: updated with FooSpecs (aka PrescriptionSpecs)

Comment: Hmm, looks ok to me. Do they work on their own, like in `fooRepo.findAll(containsUserCode("XXX"), pageable);`?

Comment: No, for now I only have this method (searchFoo). So doing `Specification.where(null)` is legit? I'm worried why while debuging I dont see the content of`spec`, the IDE is saying it's null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173755/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-anat0lius).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Specification.where(null)` works just fine.
It is annotated with `@Nullable` and the implementation handles `null` values as it should.

The problem is that you are using the `and` method as if it would modify the `Specification`, but it creates a new one. So you should use

```
spec = spec.and( ... );
```

Comment: Let's say I have 5 fields, but because they all are null, the spec is left with the value of `Specification.where(null)`. Question: is there a way to check that spec equals to `Specification.where(null)`

Comment: @IlyaSerebryannikov please don't ask new questions in comments, ask them in questions.